# Add values to Ruby JSON Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am working on Ruby on Rails. I have JSON object like this in my database:

```
{"data":[
    {"name":"A", "available":"1"},
    {"name":"B", "available":"0"}
]}
```

I want to update this by adding another record and it should look like:

```
{"data":[
        {"name":"A", "available":"1"},
        {"name":"B", "available":"0"},
        {"name":"C","available":"1"}
    ]}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: where is this other record coming from?

Comment: The other record I am creating based on user input in my website.

Comment: Is there any thing special about this object? I think this is just a basic array and hash manipulation which you know already if you have used Ruby for a while. You mention "database" and I think you might want to do something with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this

```
json = { "data" => [
         {"name" => "A", "available" => "1"},
         {"name" => "B", "available" => "0"}
       ]}
json["data"].push({"name" => "C", "available" => "1"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ActiveRecord Serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize)(Or Rails 5 attribute api), The the value will already be converted to hash.

```
class Model
 serialize :some_field, JSON
end

record = Model.find(id)

record.some_field ==>
{"data":[
    {"name":"A", "available":"1"},
    {"name":"B", "available":"0"}
]}

record.some_field["data"] << {"name" => "C", "available" => "1"}
record.save
```